# unlimited nested category in MYSQL using PHP

Tags: mysql

I want to create categories for products with no limit on how deep it can go.

[image: something like this]

is this possible. I read up on trees and  hierarchies. I'm confuse as to how i should go about. Please advice .

Comment: This can easily be achieved with a table containing an ID and a parent ID (so one record can reference another record in the same table). You may want to read up on different approaches though. I recommend to look here: https://de.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data

Comment: thank you -- ill go through it.

Answer (score 0):

have a table like this.

```
+----+-----------+------+
| id | parent_id | name |
+----+-----------+------+
```

There you go, refer `parent_id` to same table and you have what you want.
As for a query? I suggest to either get all and write some code to generate the structure or if you're going to have thousands of categories, just get all with `parent_id = 0` and query the children when you need.